# Removing stop words html tags and counting frequency of words in sentences

Tags: solr, lucene, tokenize

I have sentences like these "

**How to use:**

Choose a smooth, clean and dry surface. Peel the stickers from the sheet one by one.

Position the a" . It has html tags in them and punctuation etc. I would like to remove these html tags, punctuations, stop words etc. and then count the frequencies of each word. For eg. in the sentence above the terms would be:

```
Choose
Smooth
clean
```

while `</p>, <p>, <b> , the , from, has` etc. would be removed. I was wondering if there are any good java/scala libraries for this? For eg. like solr analyzers here http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/

Comment: Apache OpenNLP should support what you need - it's built for sentence analysis, and features tokenizers and filters. https://opennlp.apache.org/

Comment: Another option: You can use Lucene analyzers without needing to build indexes. There is a filter which [removes HTML constructs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/charfilter/HTMLStripCharFilter.html), as well as the usual text normalizers and stop-word removers (for various languages). The code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723144/using-lucene-analyzer-without-indexing-is-my-approach-reasonable) shows an example. You could use its `while` loop to build a map of terms and counts.