# standalone Lucene field analyzer without Solr

Tags: rest, solr, nlp, lucene

Is there a way to use Lucene field analyzers (possibly as REST API) without installing Solr? (it would be an overkill for my needs).

In my case I'd like to define only the analyzer pipeline, e.g.:

```
<fieldType name="text_lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and expose it as an API, technically a small subset of a full Solr instance.

I hope I've been clear enough, feel free to ask me any further explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like you may want something like this: [Using Lucene Analyzer Without Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59723144/12567365). This lets you use an analyzer without Solr and without any need to build Lucene index files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. It's in the right direction, indeed. Basically I'd like to have that kind of simplicity (e.g. chaining multiple analyzers) possibly using the XML way of doing it -as we do on Solr- and exposing them on a REST API. I'm asking much I know ;-)

Comment: I don't think you can re-use Solr XML for that. Instead, once you have your Java method containing your analyzer code, you can expose it as an API in the same way that you would expose any functionality via an API. These are really 2 distinct steps (and 2 separate SO questions): (1) Define a standalone Lucene analyzer (my code); and (2) Package it into a REST API as an endpoint (I assume you already have a framework for that).

Comment: sure, exposing an API it's doable without too much effort. but what about the configurability? What if I later need to add for example a StopWordsFilterFactory without rebuilding the whole project?

Comment: I think that is why the custom analyzer builder could be a good fit for your question. It allows you to build as many (or as few) steps (e.g. filters) as you may need, in a dynamic way. If the API call contains 3 filters, then add 3 filters. That's one benefit of the Builder approach. (If you are looking for the relevant Solr classes which probably already do the equivalent of this, then sorry, I don't know which classes those are.)

Comment: Great! It brings me one step closer to my goal. Thanks